# How to handle more than one layouts from a child page in Nuxt.js?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I am using `Nuxt.js` and `Vue.js` for the first time. So, I want to use a template as a parent which basically needs to have two columns. Each child has different data for both the columns.

`layouts/content.vue`:

```
<template>
    <b-container fluid>
        <b-row>
            <!--<b-col><nuxt/></b-col>
            <b-col><nuxt/></b-col>-->
        </b-row>
    </b-container>
</template>
```

This is let's say the child vue component:

`pages/some-page/index.vue`:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <!-- how to enter data for both the columns -->
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        layout: 'content'
    }
</script>
```

How can I enter handle both the columns of my `content.vue`? I want to make two columns in some parent layout so that for later editing, I have only one file from which changes are reflected for all child pages.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot pass data to layout (you can by using vuex), and you cannot use two times `<nuxt />`. You should use component slot instead:

`layouts/content.vue`:

```html
<template>
    <b-container fluid>
        <nuxt />
    </b-container>
</template>
```

`components/two-cols.vue`:

```html
<template>
    <b-row>
        <b-col><slot name="col-1"></slot></b-col>
        <b-col><slot name="col-2"></slot></b-col>
    </b-row>
</template>
```

`pages/some-page/index.vue`:

```html
<template>
    <two-cols>
        <template slot="col-1>
            <!-- col-1 html here -->
        </template>
        <template slot="col-2>
            <!-- col-2 html here -->
        </template>
    </two-cols>
</template>

<script>
    import TwoCols from '~/components/two-cols.vue`
    export default {
        layout: 'content',
        components: {
            TwoCols
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Just found this response from @atinux on github: https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/190#issuecomment-277304451